# How to resolve stream is not writable on node server for binary.js(BinaryStream.write)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binary.js

I am working on file upload node server, for one large file after upload I am getting below error

> Error: Stream is not writable
>       
> at BinaryStream.write (/node_modules/binaryjs/lib/stream.js:84:11)
>       
> at /src/K/Cli/upload/lib/media.js:120:36
>       
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
>       
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>       
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
>   I am using node `version v0.10.48`
>
> Reference code picked from https://github.com/rajkissu/binaryjs-upload-stream

I am unable to find the way how to resolve this.

the problem is for 1% case below code goes to `console.log('Debug 4)` case and upon executing `stream.write({end: true});` it stop node server ie., I get bad gateway, since thrown error is not handled.

and on front end I am using data from node server read content id and set done, but since node server stop and I am not able to get content id from node server.

```
bs = new BinaryServer({ port: 9004 });

bs.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {
        upload(stream, meta);
    });
});

function upload(stream, meta) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(uploadPath + '/' + meta.name);
    stream.pipe(file);
    stream.on('end', function () {

       // console.log(__dirname);
        var cli_base=__dirname+'/../../';

        var cmd = '<upload systme cmd>';
        console.log('Uploading End and running command ' + cmd);         
        try {
            stream.write({uploaded: true});
        }catch (e) {
            console.log('Debug 3, Streem On End Event : '+e.message,meta);
            //  stream.write({end: true});
        }
        if(!meta.hasOwnProperty('executed')){
            meta.executed=true;
            child = exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                try{
                    console.log(error, JSON.parse(stdout), stderr);
                    var command_output = JSON.parse(stdout);

                    if(command_output.hasOwnProperty('content_id')){
                        stream.write({end: true, content_id: command_output.content_id,files:command_output.file});
                        console.log(command_output.content_id);
                    }
                }catch (e) {                        
                   console.log('Debug 4, Streem On End Event : '+e.message,meta,child);
                   stream.write({end: true});
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: this problem could be due to using node version!! Please check your node version and add in your question.

Comment: @MuneerAlam I am using node version `v0.10.48` for this, and updated question for the same.

Comment: @Ramrantan Gupta problem can be resolved if you can update your node version (>0.12.X) or some LTS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for your problem, use options while creating file object as below

```
var options = {flags: 'w', encoding: 'utf8',fd: null,mode: '0666'};
var file = fs.createWriteStream(uploadPath + '/' + meta.name,options);
```

> Node reference https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.12.5/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options
>
> Encoding options for `createWriteStream` https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.12.5/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback